# Remove old work account office365

Tags: office365

My previous employer provided me with an Office365 subscription. I've since left that company and bought my own subscription. How can I remove the work account from the Office365 installation on my machine?

I did set up my personal account, and it's workable, but sometimes Word still tries to connect to the old work account when I start it up -- and of course it fails because the old employer has turned off that account -- and I want to stop Word from attempting this.

**EDIT:** I have tried the recommended solution and I am *still* getting prompted, as shown in this screenshot. I would greatly appreciate any insight you can offer.

[image]

Comment: Should be as simple as logging out of the account.  Can you provide a screenshot of that screen but sanitize any sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

In any Office application, click File > Account > Switch account, log out your old work account. Then, you can remove the storage service of the old work account from **Connected Services** list.

You can open **Windows Settings** and click **Accounts > Access work or school** to check the setting to see if the account is associated or not. You can disconnect the old work account if it is there.

Also, open Control Panel, click **User Accounts** and check the credential manager and remove any credentials related to the old work account.
[credential manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbhqb.jpg)

Comment: I've done all this and I am *still* getting prompted -- see screenshot I added.